# Problems adding images - list-style-image

Tags: css

I've had some problems to add the image using CSS. I coded like below, but the image doesn't show up on the website. 
I'm stuck in this part.
Can you help me to go ahead?

```
.categories li{   

list-style-image:url('C:\Users\Leandro Albuquerque\Documents\Programming\EDX Course - Studying\CSS Studying\images\check.10px.png'); 

              }
```

Comment: You shouldn't use the entire path of your pc, you should make the path since the origin directory of your project, maybe that's why doesn't work

Comment: I tried everything that W3C explained and nothing works.

Comment: I don't know the paths in you computer, but try change the `url(CSS Studying\images\check.10px.png')`

Comment: nothing happened. list-style-image:url('CSS Studying\images\check.10px.png');

Comment: I can't help because I don't know how you organize your computer folders, but don't put the entire path begining on your disk, you have to begin on your project folder, and using `../` if you want to change folder or `./` if it's the same folder...

Comment: Also, your bars are wrong, it's `/` not \

Comment: Now! You got it. :) list-style-image:url('./images/check.10px.png');  - Thank you a lot!

Comment: I'll post as an answer so you can mark it as answered, okay? :)

Comment: Okay! How can I mark as answered?

Comment: Mark as answered in the answer I wrote below :) @LeandroAlbuquerque

Answer (score 0):

where is your .css file located? and where is your image located? (im assuming the image is:  C:\Users\Leandro Albuquerque\Documents\Programming\EDX Course - Studying\CSS Studying\images\check.10px.png  ?)

Comment: I use Visual Studio Code.

Comment: the image is located at C:\Users\Leandro Albuquerque\Documents\Programming\EDX Course - Studying\CSS Studying\images\check.10px.png

Comment: Im not sure how visual studio code works but im assuming your .css file is somewhere located in your harddrive?

if your .css file is inside folder "example" and the image is inside "example/images" then change the path in your code to 'images/10px.png'

Comment: I did, but it doesn't work yet. list-style-image:url('images\check.10px.png');

Comment: hmm, try to play around with the path and you should end up fixing it

maybe renaming the "CSS Studying" file to something without a space could fix it, also maybe there should be space after ":" example: list-style-image: url

Comment: It's not working yet.                                                                         I tried this paths: list-style-image:url('C:\Users\Leandro Albuquerque\Documents\Programming\EDX\CSS\images\check.10px.png');    list-style-image:url('C:\Documents\Programming\EDX\CSS\images\check.10px.png');

Comment: list-style-image:url('C:\images\check.10px.png');                                                     list-style-image:url('images\check.10px.png');                                                                 list-style-image:url('check.10px.png');

Answer (score 0):

I can't really help because I don't know how you organize your computer folders, but start by not putting the entire path begining on your disk, you have to begin on your project folder, and using `../` if you want to change folder or `./`.

Also, and very important, your bars are wrong,  it's `/`, not `\`.